# Selecting specific set of data while using @DataProvider in test

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, testng

I wonder if it is possible to have two or more test using one @DataProvider class but with different data file used? I don't know how to specify in addannotation which file I am using. Sorry if my question is haotic. This is my first time asking question here :)

I have a test class with @DataProvider method providing data from excel file. I am trying to add couple tests where each test is using that method but with different file:

```
private static final String excel1 = "excel1 .xlsx";
private static final String excel2 = "excel1 .xlsx";

@Test
    @UseDataProvider("dataProvider")
    public void test1(Object[][] dataFromExcel1) {
// method body
    }

@Test
    @UseDataProvider("dataProvider")
    public void test1(Object[][] dataFromExcel2) {
// method body
    }

    @DataProvider
    public static Object[][] dataProvider(String excelName) throws IOException {
        return DataForTestProvider.provideDataForProjectTest(excelName, 1, 16);
    }

    public static Object[][] provideDataForProjectTest(String file, int min, int max) throws IOException {
        int dif = max - min + 1;
        int maxNumOfColumns = getNumberOfColumns(file);

        Object[][] providedData = new Object[dif][maxNumOfColumns + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < dif; i++) {
            providedData[i][0] = min + 1;

            for (int j = 1; j <= maxNumOfColumns; j++) {
                providedData[i][j] = returnExcelCell(file, min, j - 1);
            }

            min++;
        }

        return providedData;
    }
```